# Best way to improve build times/pipeline with a Windows focused c++ app?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, containers, devops

My teammate and I work for a small dev team and have become 'the build and pipeline guys'. We're moving to the next big version of our legacy application, and have been researching ways to renovate the production process for this 20 year old dinosaur. Lucky us, right?

It's a windows focused cpp app built with CMake, and visual studio...2012. We're now switching to VS 2022 but not without issues so far. We are also switching from Azure DevOps to Jira.

Although we produce a Linux version of the app, it is more of an afterthought, and after several weeks of gauging the current state of windows containerization, we're currently discouraged about the prospect of implementing a solution that fits our use case with minimal overhead--we're not interested in building a rocket ship to cross the street. We've been looking into docker and orchestrators, but the consensus seems to be that most of these tools aren't the best for us windows plebs.

We have access to a very beefy windows server that's not reaching a fraction of its capacity. Our current CI/CD utilizes tfs with a few basic VM's. Past few days we've been messing with distcc and docker to speed up compile time by distributing compile jobs, but distcc is also linux based.

Are we stuck in the stone age?

Comment: *"become 'the build and pipeline guys'."* - so in other words,  the guys everyone blames when things go wrong, whilst simultaneously being rudely discounted when everything is working. Lucky you. I assume you're cmake system is already ninja'd?

Comment: "I assume you're cmake system is already ninja'd?" Negative. Right now we're using CMake and VS2022 on Windows and messing with VSCode on Linux.